# ActiveRecord: How to set the "changed" property of an model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

For every model in ActiveRecord, there seems to be a private property called "changed", which is an array listing all the fields that have changed since you retrieved the record from the database.

Example:

```
a = Article.find(1)
a.shares = 10
a.url = "TEST"

a.changed ["shares", "url"]
```

Is there anyway to set this "changed" property yourself? I know it sounds hacky/klunky, but I am doing something rather unordinary, which is using Redis to cache/retrieve objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveModel::Dirty#changed` returns keys of the `@changed_attributes` hash, which itself returns attribute names and their original values:

```
a = Article.find(1)
a.shares = 10
a.url = "TEST"

a.changed #=> ["shares", "url"]
a.changed_attributes #=> {"shares" => 9, "url" => "BEFORE_TEST"}
```

Since there is no setter method `changed_attributes=`, you can set the instance variable by force:

```
a.instance_variable_set(:@changed_attributes, {"foo" => "bar"})
a.changed #=> ["foo"]
```

Answer (score 1):

See this example from: [Dirty Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Dirty

  define_attribute_methods :name

  def name
    @name
  end

  def name=(val)
    name_will_change! unless val == @name
    @name = val
  end

  def save
    @previously_changed = changes
    @changed_attributes.clear
  end
end
```

So, if you have a attribute `foo` and want to "change" that just call `foo_will_change!`.